# Remove integers from list

Tags: list, scheme, lisp, racket

I have a strange problem that couple of hours can't implement in Scheme.
Let's say we have:

```
(define x '( (Orlando (NY 3))
             (Chicago (Montana 5) (Orlando 8))
             ...and so on ...
           )
```

I want to transform it to

```
'( (Orlando NY)
   (Chicago Montana Orlando)
    ...and so on ...
 )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please note that "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.**" Thank you for showing the expected results, but in the future, if you've spent a "couple of hours", please show at least some of the attempts from that time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also try

```
(map 
 (lambda (x) (cons (car x) (map car (cdr x)))) 
 x)
```