# delete sublist by element occurrence (Scheme)

Tags: algorithm, list, scheme, lisp

How I could remove a sublist by searching only one elem from it.

For example, let's have the list:

```
( (pacific (atlanta ohaio) (NY LI))
  (atlanta (pacific blue) (ohaio green)) )
```

And I want to remove "pacific" from the list and to get:

```
( (pacific (atlanta ohaio) (NY LI))
  (atlanta (ohaio green)) )
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated :).

Comment: Your example deletes a leaf in the tree, not a sublist. Please clarify.

Comment: I edited my question: I want to delete the sublist that contain the searched word (or it is called leaf?)

Comment: Looking at this and your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20749277/remove-integers-from-list), you may want to make some sort of data structure to suite this information in; lists may make it harder to deal with than some specialized data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The criteria for deleting an element from the input list is not stated clearly in the question. This will work for the example shown:

```
(define lst
  '((pacific (atlanta ohaio) (NY LI))
    (atlanta (pacific blue) (ohaio green))))

(map (lambda (slst)
       (filter (lambda (e)
                 (not (and (list? e) (member 'pacific e))))
               slst))
     lst)

=> '((pacific (atlanta ohaio) (NY LI)) (atlanta (ohaio green)))
```

If necessary, for other inputs you can tweak the condition in the innermost lambda until the result is as desired. For instance, I interpreted the comment in the question:

> I want to delete the sublist that contains the searched word

As: "find the searched word in *any position* inside a sublist"; if the searched word can be found in, say, only the first position then adjust the condition accordingly.

Comment: ah, You make it far far simpler than my solution, THANKS :)