# Recursively creating list in scheme

Tags: list, recursion, scheme, racket, tail-recursion

I come up again with my strange Scheme questions.

I have a definition that remove subelement(based on search occurrence) from a list and generate new list without it (based on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771344/delete-sublist-by-element-occurrence-scheme)).

```
(func '1 mylist) ; will return mylist without all sublists containing 1
```

All was working fine until I realized that I need to repeat my definition for each element in another list.

I call it recursively, but with every call I use the original list not the previous filtered.

Or with another words I want to achieve this:

```
(define filterList '(1 2 3))

(func '3 (func '2 (func '1 mylist) ); list without all sublists containig 1 2 3
```

I'm tottaly stuck. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: show ... us ... your ... code ... *please*.

Comment: Thanks for the respond. uselpa already helped me :)

Comment: that's besides the point. You should always include your code in your question, that's the rule on SO. The Q&A entries on SO are to be helpful in general, not just to you personally. :)

Comment: @WillNess is right. If you post the part of code you already have, it's so much easier to help. Your definition of `func` would have been useful, and even the bit of code you posted is inconsistent (list called `filterList`, but in the call you use `mylist`). If we got something we can simply cut/paste into our environment (whether the code is working or not) the answers you get will be better.

Comment: actually 'func' is slightly modified version of another my question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771344/delete-sublist-by-element-occurrence-scheme. I will add it to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic loop over the lists of elements (elts) to remove from the initial list (lst):

```
(define (func2 elts lst)
  (if (null? elts)
      lst
      (func2 (cdr elts) (func (car elts) lst))))
```

then

```
(func2 '(1 3) '(1 2 3))
=> '(2)
```

or, in Racket:

```
(define (func2 elts lst)
  (for/fold ((res lst)) ((e (in-list elts)))
    (func e res)))
```

Comment: ah...sometimes I feel like I'm the dumbest person in the world...Thanks again @uselpa.

Comment: Time for a break, maybe ;-)